# does html5 appcache cause the page to load slower?

Tags: html, offline

The files listed in the .mf file are the same files i am trying to load when the page first runs. Does having a manifest attribute defer processing of the rest of the document until the appcache loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. On the very first load the cache gets built in the background, using the same files that where just downloaded, provided they have proper cache settings. E.g. If you have foo.css with long cache headers in your HTML page and the manifest, the browser will:

- Load and render the page.
- Look at the manifest.
- Load foo.css from browser cache to appcache.

BUT: Appcache will however result in a FOUC (brief white page on reload), even if online and the page/app was made well enough so far to show smooth reloads.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this. ...The system I was working on took a completely non-standard approach which is probably why it didnt click. (e.g. download index.htm but in appcache it's mySession/index.htm. why? WHY!?)

Comment: Glad it helped... Check http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html & http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag for more details, especially the later provides a few neat tricks like loading the manifest from a file in an iframe to avoid adding the current page to the appcache if you want to load it from the server if the user is online.

Answer (score 0):

With AppCache, the browser loads the document and its associated resources directly from the cache, without accessing the network, so this should load just as fast if not faster.